# How to use two ng-container with two different arrays iteration in a table?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let result of results">                             
    <th [ngClass]= "option1 || option2 ? 'class1': 'class2' "> 
        <div [ngClass]= " option1  || option2 ? 'class1': 'class2'" class = "header-cell">
            <div [ngClass]= " option1 || option2 ? 'class3': 'class4' " class = "day-header-data">  
                    
                <div> {{ result.initial</div>
                <div class = "date"> 
                    {{ result.date | date: 'dd/MM' }}    
                </div>
          
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </th>
</ng-container>
```

What I want to do is in the **div** with date I want to use another iterated value. I need to iterate
***ngFor = "let date of dates" and use {{ date | date: 'dd/MM' }}.**

If I do something like this it crashes:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let date of dates">
    <ng-container *ngFor = "let result of results">
                                    
        <th [ngClass]= "option1 || option2 ? 'class1': 'class2' "> 
            <div [ngClass]= " option1  || option2 ? 'class1': 'class2'" class = "header-cell">
                <div [ngClass]= " option1 || option2 ? 'class3': 'class4' " class = "day-header-data">  
                        
                    <div> {{ result.initial</div>
                    <div class = "date"> 
                        {{ date | date: 'dd/MM' }}    
                    </div>
              
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </th>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

That happens because to get results I need to wait a bit since it comes from an http request while dates is a simple array of dates I already have.

How can I do it? In which way I can move the divs? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add the error in the question? What fails the for loop or the other things?

Answer (score 0):

To handle HTTP request result use? `{{ result?.initial }`

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let date of dates">
    <ng-container *ngFor = "let result of results">
                                    
        <th [ngClass]= "option1 || option2 ? 'class1': 'class2' "> 
            <div [ngClass]= " option1  || option2 ? 'class1': 'class2'" class = "header-cell">
                <div [ngClass]= " option1 || option2 ? 'class3': 'class4' " class = "day-header-data">  
                        
                    <div> {{ result?.initial }}</div>
                    <div class = "date"> 
                        {{ date | date: 'dd/MM' }}    
                    </div>
              
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </th>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```